# Word/phrase for "the one that brings bad luck" (e.g. to a group)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> I've always considered myself a/as [...].

I thought of *black cat*. But I think it's a little ambiguous and weird to use it in this situation.

Comment: "I've always considered myself a Charlie Brown.", although the reference is likely obscure to a younger audience.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187944/a-phrase-for-extremely-bad-luck/187948#187948

Comment: [Joe Btfsplk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Btfsplk).  Of course, the problem (call it bad luck) is that no one really knows how to pronounce it.

Comment: I've heard black cat in this context; as the black cat in the situation, I rather appreciated the ambiguity...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***Jinx*** is likely the word you are looking for, as in

***I have always considered myself jinxed*** but it is also possible to say

***I have always considered myself a jinx***

Wikipedia: [**Jinx**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx)

> - A type of curse placed on a person that makes them prey to many minor misfortunes and other forms of bad luck;
> - A person afflicted with a similar curse, who, while not directly subject to a series of misfortunes, seems to attract them to anyone in his vicinity.

<sub>Source: Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: So, it's common to say: "I always considered myself a jinx?"

Comment: You could say: I have always considered myself as jinxed. But, more often I hear a simple: I'm jinxed.

Comment: It's closed now, but I would also suggest 'cursed' although it's not as to the point as jinxed.   **I think my curse is bringing down the luck of the team**

Comment: @ajacian81 I think 'jinx' works better than 'cursed'. The person who's cursed is usually the one who suffers the bad luck (with those around them perhaps suffering "collateral damage"); the person who's jinxed doesn't seem to experience any direct bad luck themselves, but misfortune seems to befall those in close proximity or association with them.

Comment: A jinx is both the curse and the cursed person.

Answer (score 14):

A word which might be applied to a person is **Jonah,** from the Biblical story of Jonah (of whale fame).

He was taking a sea voyage and storms threatened to sink the ship because God was displeased with him fleeing. The sailors drew lots to find the cause of the bad luck, chose Jonah and dumped him overboard to get rid of him. The storm stopped immediately.

The full story is in [Jonah Chapter 1](http://biblehub.com/jonah/1.htm).

Comment: Another Biblical reference may be *Job*.

Comment: However Job was not the cause of bad luck - he was manipulated by external forces

Comment: @mplungjan: I believe most people would consider a *jinx* or a *curse* to be an external force. The key point is that if the group success depends upon Job having good fortune, the group will fail.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative term derived from traditional folk spirituality that developed from a number of West African, Native American and European spiritual traditions is:

[Hoodoo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hoodoo): (fromTFD)

> - (Other Non-Christian Religions) a variant of voodoo
> - **a person or thing that brings bad luck**
> - bad luck

Answer (score 1):

[Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_(metaphor)) famously foretold ill fortunes and calamities which nobody believed in, she was said to be cursed by Apollo after she had refused his sexual advances. In that sense a Cassandra would be anyone (man or woman) who issues a warning about an awful event and whose prediction is later verified. The misfortune falls on others and not on the teller.

> Sometimes the name Cassandra is applied to those who can predict
> rises, falls, and particularly crashes on the global stock market, as
> happened with Warren Buffett, who repeatedly warned that the 1990s
> stock market surge was a bubble, attracting to him the title of 'Wall
> Street Cassandra'.

<sup>Source: Wikipedia</sup>

Comment: She did not cause them so I would think this is a side issue

Comment: @mplungjan I upvoted your answer and Andrew's too but a person who is "famous" for predicting ill things to occur can be said to be a Cassandra, and people could, rightly or wrongly, want to avoid being in their presence to be on the "safe side".

Answer (score 0):

A monkey's paw?

That's a little different to what you asked, I guess

Answer (score -2):

how about a "bad omen". I consider myself as a bad omen ?

Comment: A better term would be [albatross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatross_(metaphor)) _"The word albatross is sometimes used metaphorically to mean a psychological burden that feels like a curse."_.